# Accidentally edited the etc/network/interfaces without sudo

Tags: networking

very new to this all, and have had a heckuva time trying to get WiFi up and running (i did it once before on another Pi).

I keep getting the error 
Reconfiguring network interfaces.../etc/network/interfaces:36 misplaced option
ifdown: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"

I have looked at line 36 of interfaces a hundred times and retyped it (it is the wpa-ssid "network" line). Then I tried ls -l /etc/network and saw that a bunch of possibly related files : interfaces, interfaces~, interfaces.dpkg-old, interfaces.ori. I noticed that interfaces has pi pi in front of it instead of root root (and interfaces~ has root pi).

Could that be the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

My /etc/network/interfaces contains

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   wpa-ssid gtyroove
   wpa-psk pJk27WsqdHK3724ssdg233q19GdPrPSL
```

My /etc/network directory contains

```
$ ls -l /etc/network
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  6 23:16 if-down.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  6 22:38 if-post-down.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  6 22:38 if-pre-up.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  6 23:16 if-up.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  173 Jun 21 20:33 interfaces
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  171 May  6 22:39 interfaces.dpkg-old
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   12 May  6 22:18 run -> /run/network
```

Check that you have similar entries.  It seems that the interface file should be owner root group root.

Comment: Thanks!! I ended up: mv interfaces.dpkb-old interfaces, and then rewrote interfaces, rebooted, and it worked!!

Comment: @joan I don't know how your network is configured, but assuming that is a real passphrase and SSID you may want to remove or change them for security purposes.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I used made up phrases.